# Visual Studio Project System encountered an error

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 API project with Docker for Windows Support that used to load/build/run fine until a few days back but now it throws me an error as soon as I load the solution in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.0 Preview 6.0

Here is the **error**:
[image: Project System error]

Here is the information from the **diagnostic log** mentioned in the error:

Recoverable
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

at EnvDTE.Projects.Item(Object index)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Shared.HierarchyExtensions.IsInStartupProjects(Hierarchy hierarchy, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.ProjectSystem.ProjectLoadHandler.d__31.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.AutoLoadMethodStateMachine.<b__8_0>d.MoveNext()

Finally, here is the **project file**:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
        <UserSecretsId>d0fb3109-adbd-446a-ab61-283a4cce9594</UserSecretsId> 
        <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\..\..\docker
        compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="7.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="CorrelationId" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.0.100" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.100" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.0.2105168" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Dlls\Co.Bll.PostService\Co.Bll.PostService.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Dlls\Co.Dal\Co.Dal.Posts.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Dlls\Co.Dtos\Co.Dtos.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Dlls\Co.Framework\Co.Framework.csproj" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

I even commented the Docker related property group items and rebuilt the solution but it didn't work. Furthemore, when I run the API locally in Chrome, I get the following error message:

[image: Runtime error]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the project file and how do I fix it?

Comment: VS *ought* to handle failures gracefully.  Please open a feedback ticket so that the product team can investigate this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/382613/systemargumentexception-the-parameter-is-incorrect.html

> We have fixed the problem in an upcoming release. This is planned to go out in an upcoming servicing update to VS2017, currently planned for 15.9.4.